# Why is my code not outputting a string when I scan an integer before it, but outputting the string when I scan the integer after?

Tags: c

This is a really basic scanf/printf problem, but for some reason I'm getting stuck trying to get my program to properly read and print a string.  If I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int    userInt;
   double userDouble;
   char userChar = 'z';
   char userString[8];
   // FIXME: Define char and string variables similarly
   
   
   printf("Enter integer:\n");
   scanf("%d", &userInt);
   printf("Enter character:\n");
   scanf("%c", &userChar);
   printf("Enter string:\n");
   scanf("%s", userString);
   
   
   printf("%d %c %s", userInt, userChar, userString); 
      
   return 0;
```

using these inputs

```
23 a howdy
```

I get the following output:

```
Enter integer:
Enter character:
Enter string:
23   a
```

If I run the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int    userInt;
   double userDouble;
   char userChar = 'z';
   char userString[8];
   // FIXME: Define char and string variables similarly
   
   
   
   printf("Enter character:\n");
   scanf("%c", &userChar);
   printf("Enter string:\n");
   scanf("%s", userString);
   printf("Enter integer:\n");
   scanf("%d", &userInt);
   
   
   printf("%d %c %s", userInt, userChar, userString); 

return 0;
```

run with the following inputs:

```
a howdy 23
```

I get this output, which is what I've been expecting.

```
Enter character:
Enter string:
Enter integer:
23 a howdy
```

My problem is that I have to scan the integer before the character and string for the problem I'm working on, and I can't figure out why the second method works while the first one doesn't.  Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: When you say "run with the following inputs" how are you giving it those inputs?

Comment: It's through zybooks.  I'm just putting 23 a howdy and a howdy 23, respectively, in the box that says "Enter program input".

Comment: `scanf("%d", &userInt);` that only consumes `23` from the input. Everything after that is still in `stdin`, including the space immediately after the `23`. So the next  `scanf("%c", &userChar);` reads the space and then `scanf("%s", userString);` reads the `a`.

Comment: That makes so much sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` usually discards leading whitespace, but not `%c`, because then you wouldn't be able to read a whitespace character.

> Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added). ***The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.*** To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

To walk through this... you input `23 a howdy`. Let's look at what's on the input stream as each are called.

```
// "23 a howdy"
scanf("%d", &userInt); // reads 23

// " a howdy"
scanf("%c", &userChar); // reads a single character, a space.

// "a howdy"
scanf("%s", userString); // reads up to the next whitespace, 'a'

// " howdy" remains on input.
```

And if we print these with quotes around them to see the whitespace...

```
// 23 ' ' 'a'
printf("%d '%c' '%s'\n", userInt, userChar, userString);
```

To get `%c` to skip whitespace, put a space in front of it.

```
scanf(" %c", &userChar);
```

[`scanf` is full of these sorts of pitfalls](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), you can never be quite sure what's left on the input buffer. For this reason, it's safer to separate the reading from the scanning. Use `fgets` to read up to a newline and parse with `sscanf`.

Comment: You can always be sure of exactly what is left on the input buffer -- you just need to be careful and understand the subtle differences and limitations of the various conversions.

Comment: The one case you can't really deal with in scanf is integer overflow, which is tricky in any case.